# How can I pass a variable to loadInBackground() in a Loader class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, loader

```
public class BookLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Book>> {

    public BookLoader(Context context, String baseRequestUrl) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> loadInBackground() {
        /** Tag for log messages */
         String LOG_TAG = BookLoader.class.getName();
        final String APP_ID = "booklisting-174212";
        Log.e( " REQUEST is: trial 2 : "+baseRequestUrl );
        BASE_REQUEST_URL += key;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " Request url : "+BASE_REQUEST_URL );
        return null;
    }



}
```

I want to be able to use baseRequestUrl in the loadInBackground function , How can I achieve that ?

Comment: create instance variable in BookLoader  class and  assign in constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 public class BookLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Book>> {
        String baseRequestUrl;
        public BookLoader(Context context, String baseRequestUrl) {
            super(context);
            this.baseRequestUrl=baseRequestUrl;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            super.onStartLoading();
            forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Book> loadInBackground() {
             //user url here
            /** Tag for log messages */
             String LOG_TAG = BookLoader.class.getName();
            final String APP_ID = "booklisting-174212";
            Log.e( " REQUEST is: trial 2 : "+baseRequestUrl );
            BASE_REQUEST_URL += key;
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " Request url : "+BASE_REQUEST_URL );
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !I'm grateful.